# Programmatically override a storyboard reference?

Tags: ios, storyboard

In my iOS app's main storyboard, I have a UITabViewController with triggered segues to some storyboard references to view controllers, one per each tab. Let's say the tabs are "Cats", "Dogs", and "Gold Fish"

A new product requirement has come in. We want to have the first tab vary based on a runtime condition. How do I programmatically change the storyboard reference to the "Cats" view controller to say.. the new "Ferrets" view controller?

Comment: trigger the segue programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the view controllers of a tab bar controller over its property `viewControllers`, e.g.

```
let tabBarController = ...
var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers

viewControllers[0] = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Ferrets")
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
```